# Push error in dolist

Tags: lisp

```
(defun remov(l)
  (defparameter z ())
  (setq contor 0)
  (setq counter 0)
  (dolist (elem l) 
    (if
        (or (< (expt 2 contor) counter) (> (expt 2 contor) counter)) 
        ((push elem z) (setq contor (+ 1 contor))) (setq counter (+ 1 counter)))
    )


  (print e)
  )
```

Why do I get `Error: Illegal function object: (PUSH ELEM Z).
[condition type: TYPE-ERROR]`?
What does this mean?

Comment: You have an extra set of parentheses before `(push elem z)`.

Comment: Didn't I tell you in your earlier question that you should not put `defparameter` inside a function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LISP "Error Illegal function object..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213605/lisp-error-illegal-function-object)

Comment: Looks like you're attempting to write C code in Lisp. You'll probably have more success if you stop doing that and learn Lisp instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please learn how indentation and whitespace is used in Lisp, and where newlines help and where they do not.

```
(defun remov (l)
  (defparameter z ())
  (setq contor 0)
  (setq counter 0)
  (dolist (elem l) 
    (if (or (< (expt 2 contor) counter)
            (> (expt 2 contor) counter))
        ((push elem z) (setq contor (+ 1 contor)))
        (setq counter (+ 1 counter))))
  (print e))
```

The immediate problem: `if` takes three arguments, evaluates the first, then evaluates and returns either the second or the third.  The second form is:

```
((push elem z) (setq contor (+ 1 contor)))
```

The first element of an evaluated form is the operator, which is either the name of a function or special operator, or a lambda expression.  A lambda expression is a form like `(lambda (x) ...)`.  Here, `(push elem z)` does not fit that description.  That is the error you are getting.

Your intent seems to be to do two things, one after another.  That is usually done in a `progn` form.

```
(progn
  (push elem z)
  (setq contor (+ 1 contor)))
```

This yields:

```
(defun remov (l)
  (defparameter z ())
  (setq contor 0)
  (setq counter 0)
  (dolist (elem l) 
    (if (or (< (expt 2 contor) counter)
            (> (expt 2 contor) counter))
        (progn
          (push elem z)
          (setq contor (+ 1 contor)))
        (setq counter (+ 1 counter))))
  (print e))
```

Now, that `defparameter`.  This makes `z` a *globally special variable*.  After you have called this function at least once, `z` will be *special* anywhere in your whole program.  That is not what you want.  It seems that you simply want to establish a new local binding.  Use `let` for that.

```
(defun remov (l)
  (let ((z ()))
    (setq contor 0)
    (setq counter 0)
    (dolist (elem l) 
      (if (or (< (expt 2 contor) counter)
              (> (expt 2 contor) counter))
          (progn
            (push elem z)
            (setq contor (+ 1 contor)))
          (setq counter (+ 1 counter))))
    (print e)))
```

Then, you have the two `setq` forms.  Unless you have created a binding of `contor` and `counter` outside of the shown code, this code has undefined behaviour ("anything might happen").  `Setq` does not establish a new binding.  It seems that you just want to establish new local bindings, just like with `z`.  Use the `let` form.

```
(defun remov (l)
  (let ((z ())
        (contor 0)
        (counter 0))
    (dolist (elem l) 
      (if (or (< (expt 2 contor) counter)
              (> (expt 2 contor) counter))
          (progn
            (push elem z)
            (setq contor (+ 1 contor)))
          (setq counter (+ 1 counter))))
    (print e)))
```

Now the `let` establishes local bindings for `z`, `contor` and `counter`.

Last error: `e` is not bound in the code shown.  I have no idea what you want to do here, but I assume that you just want to return `z` after you took such pains to create it.  Since you loop over `l` and `push` into `z`, `z` has the reverse order in comparison to the corresponding values of `l`.  The idiom, if you want to have the same order, is to use `nreverse` at the end.  A function returns the value of the last form.

```
(defun remov (l)
  (let ((z ())
        (contor 0)
        (counter 0))
    (dolist (elem l) 
      (if (or (< (expt 2 contor) counter)
              (> (expt 2 contor) counter))
          (progn
            (push elem z)
            (setq contor (+ 1 contor)))
          (setq counter (+ 1 counter))))
    (nreverse z)))
```

Now, let's simplify a bit.  To `setq` a variable to `1+` its value, use the macro `incf`.  `(Incf foo)` expands to something like `(setq foo (1+ foo))`.

```
(defun remov (l)
  (let ((z ())
        (contor 0)
        (counter 0))
    (dolist (elem l) 
      (if (or (< (expt 2 contor) counter)
              (> (expt 2 contor) counter))
          (progn
            (push elem z)
            (incf contor))
          (incf counter)))
    (nreverse z)))
```

If an integer `a` is either `>` or `<` than something, it is `/=`.

```
(defun remov (l)
  (let ((z ())
        (contor 0)
        (counter 0))
    (dolist (elem l) 
      (if (/= (expt 2 contor) counter)
          (progn
            (push elem z)
            (incf contor))
          (incf counter)))
    (nreverse z)))
```

I tend to avoid abbreviations for names.

```
(defun remove-when-foo (list)
  (let ((result ())
        (contor 0)
        (counter 0))
    (dolist (element list) 
      (if (/= (expt 2 contor) counter)
          (progn
            (push element result)
            (incf contor))
          (incf counter)))
    (nreverse z)))
```

I am a bit surprised about that logic, since the condition for the `if` form will always be true in this loop.  That is why I named it `remove-when-foo`.  I guess that correcting this is your next endeavour.

Comment: Excellent answer! If I could upvote it more than once, I would.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to execute multiple expressions as a block, you have to use `progn`, you can't just wrap them in a list. The first element of a list is expected to be the function to call, and `(push elem z)` is not a valid function.

```
(if
    (or (< (expt 2 contor) counter) (> (expt 2 contor) counter)) 
    (progn
      (push elem z)
      (setq contor (+ 1 contor)))
    (setq counter (+ 1 counter)))
)
```